# Can we compute potential at a point near a uniformly charged rod using these two different routes in calculus?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, voltage, coulombs-law

Consider a uniformly charged rod of length $L$ and a point $P$ on the horizontal line of symmetry, depicted below

[image]

The ultimate goal in the calculations that follow is to find the potential at $P$.

This question is more about the math involved and whether it is possible to do the calculations in the manner explained in "method 2" below.

**Method 1**

First let me show the way that I find the easiest.

An infinitesimal charge $dq$ on the rod generates an electric field that exerts a force on a test charge $q$ at $P$, and this force is

$$d\vec{F}=\frac{kqdq}{r^2}\hat{r}\tag{1}$$

where our coordinate system has its origin at the position of $dq$ on the rod. Then, we can compute the potential at $P$ due to $dq$ by computing the negative of the work done per unit charge by the field to bring the unit charge from infinitely far away to $P$

$$W_{\infty, P} = \int_C d\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}=kqdq\int_{\infty}^r r^{-2}dr=-\frac{kqdq}{r}=-U_P\tag{2}$$

$$dV_P = \frac{U(r)}{q}=\frac{kdq}{r}\tag{3}$$

We can use the principle of superposition for potentials to obtain the potential at $P$ due to the entire rod. We now use a different coordinate system with origin at the center of the rod.

$$V_P = \int_{rod} dV=\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} \frac{kQdy_s}{L\sqrt{x_p^2+y_s^2}}\tag{4}$$

$$=\frac{kQ}{L}\ln{\left (\frac{L+\sqrt{L^2+4x_p^2}}{-L+\sqrt{L^2+4x_p^2}}\right )}\tag{5}$$

where we used $dq=\lambda dy_s=\frac{Q}{L}dy_s$.

**Method 2**

Could we have done the calculations slightly differently? Let's see.

Let's compute the total force at point $P$ due to the entire rod.

$$\vec{F}=\int_{rod} d\vec{F}=\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} \frac{kqQdy_s}{L(x_p^2+y_s^2)^{3/2}}\vec{r}_{dq,q}\tag{6}$$

$$=\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} \frac{kqQdy_s}{L(x_p^2+y_s^2)^{3/2}}(x_P\hat{i} -y_s\hat{j})$$

$$=\frac{2kqQ\arctan{\frac{L}{2x_P}}}{L}\hat{r}\tag{7}$$

Note that this is a function of $x_p$.

Can we now compute work along the line of symmetry as

$$W_{\infty,P} = \int_C \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}\tag{8}$$

where $\vec{r}=x_P\hat{r}$ and $d\vec{r}=dx_P\hat{r}$

$$W_{\infty,P} = \int_{\infty}^{x_P} \frac{2kqQ\arctan{\frac{L}{2x_P}}}{L}\ dx_P\tag{9}$$

Potential at $P$ would then be the negative of this work divided by $q$.

My question is if this is actually true. Ie, if the reasoning in method 2 is correct, and if solving (9), changing the sign, and dividing by $q$ would give the same result as in (5).

Answer (score 1):

The methods are, in principle, equivalent.  Basically, the steps are:

- Figure out the work required, due to a piece $dq$ of the rod, to bring in a charge $q$ from infinity to a given point.
- Divide by $q$ to get the potential.
- Integrate over the pieces of the rod.

In principle, it doesn't matter if you do the second and third steps in that order (method 1), or if you reverse them (method 2).  The result will be the same either way.

However, you have made an error in your method 2.  Specifically, your vector $\hat{r}$ varies over the various points on the rod.  So when you do your integral for $\vec{F}$ you have to take into account how this varies;  you can't just treat it like a constant that you can pull out of the integral.  The better way to do it is to find $F_x$ and $F_y$ due to each infinitesimal element of the rod and then do the two integrals separately.

Comment: Is the error you are referring to in equation (6)? Indeed I needed to use $\vec{r}_{dq,q}=x_P\hat{i}-y_s\hat{j}$, and I have made that change, which resulted in a factor of $x_P$ disappearing from the denominator in (7). As for the integral in (9), I am using a path that is on the x-axis. The error is not there, right? The force at any point on this line of symmetry that P is on only has a component in the $\hat{i}$ direction.